# Dynamic rendering with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using React with TypeScript, I try to dynamically render components based on a field name

```
// Referencing all components
const components = {
  ComponentA,
  ComponentB,
};

// Dynamic render the component based on fieldName
const displayComponent = (
  fieldName: keyof typeof components,
  content: ComponentType
): React.ReactNode => {
  const FieldNameComponent = components[fieldName];
  return <FieldNameComponent item={content} />;
};
```

My types:

```
type ComponentTypeA = {
  title: string;
  content: string;
};

type ComponentTypeB = {
  title: string;
  excerpt: string;
};

type ComponentType = ComponentTypeA | ComponentTypeB;
```

The compiler is not happy because it doesn't know which type to use (Component1 or Component2 which have different properties). I get this error

> Type 'ComponentType' is not assignable to type 'ComponentTypeA & ComponentTypeB'.
>
> Type 'ComponentTypeA' is not assignable to type 'ComponentTypeB & ComponentTypeA'.
>
> Type 'ComponentTypeA' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentTypeB': excerpt

So I have tried this way:

```
const displayComponent = (
  fieldName: keyof typeof components,
  content: ComponentType
) => {
  if (content instanceof ComponentTypeA) {
    return <ComponentA item={content} />;
  } else if (content instanceof ComponentTypeB) {
    return <ComponentB item={content} />;
  }
};
```

But the error remains even with the `instanceof` test.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? You don't set the return type on those functions. Shouldn't the return type be ```ComponentType```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a type guard:

```
function isComponentTypeA(type: unknown): type is ComponentTypeA {
    return type && "title" in type && "content" in type;
}
```

And you would use it in the condition:

```
  if (isComponentTypeA(content)) {
    return <ComponentA item={content} />; // inferred as ComponentTypeA
  } else if (isComponentTypeB(content)) { // another type guard if needed
    return <ComponentB item={content} />; // inferred as ComponentTypeB
  }
```

Comment: Are you telling, I can not make a dynamic render with TS, like this `const FieldNameComponent = components[fieldName];
  return <FieldNameComponent item={content} />;`

Comment: That is possible, just not with your current function signature. If you want to do dynamic rendering, why don't you change the question to that instead?

Comment: Good suggestion, title updated

Comment: thanks for you answer. How can I preserve the dynamic rendering? Without a type guard for each component. If I have to write a type guard for each component, and then test it, the dynamic rendering will be far more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to solve this error this way:

```
const displayComponent = (
  content: ComponentType
): React.ReactNode => {
  switch (content.fieldName) {
    case "ComponentA":
      return <ComponentA item={ content as ComponentAType}/>
    case "ComponentB":
      return <ComponentB item={ content as ComponentBType}/>
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

But I pretty unhappy with this, because if I have to deal with a lot to components, the switch statement will be so long... A better approach is welcome.